# difference between `spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server` and `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`

Tags: spring-cloud

I am new to the Spring Cloud, what is the exact difference between 
`spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server` and `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server` ?

When we should go for **spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server** and **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server**?

What is the business implication of these two ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference, it's just a naming convention in Spring Cloud.

Since Spring Cloud Edgware, use of the deprecated starter will log a warning with the name of the new starter to use in its place.

For your first question : It's highly recommended to go for **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-...** instead of **spring-cloud-starter-...**

Second question : no business implication. Maybe you should think about next releases to be conform.

You can find more details on [Spring Cloud Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes)